# How come I can upload gallery images for one user, but not another?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, gallery

I am creating a gallery on my website and I have created several test accounts to make sure it works for each of them. But I only seem to be able to upload any image to the screen and gallery database for only one user, and not any other. Why is this - each user has their own session so I'm very confused. Please have a look at my code. My thoughts are that there is something wrong with my putGalleryImage function in my model but I don't see anything that really sticks out at me. Im thinking it could also be in the else statement of my upload function for when an upload of an image occurs but again, nothing sticks out at me because if it works for just one specific user, why not any other?

Controller:

```
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    // Call the parent construct
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model("profiles");
    $this->load->model("gal_model");
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->gallery_path = 'web-project-jb/assets/gallery/';

}

function upload()
{

    $config = array(

            'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
            'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
            'max_size' => 10000,
            'max_width' => 1024,
            'max_height' => 768);

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $viewData['username'] = $username;

        $viewData['images'] = $this->gal_model->getGalleryImage($username);

        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
        $this->load->view('shared/nav');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $error, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');



    }
    else
    {
        $file_data  = $this->upload->data();

        $galleryImage = $this->gallery_path.$file_data['file_name'];

        $data['galleryImage'] = $this->gallery_path.$file_data['file_name'];

        $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $images = $this->session->userdata('images');

        $data['images'] = $images;

        $this->gal_model->putGalleryImage($username, $galleryImage);

        $viewData['username'] = $username;

        $viewData['images'] = $this->gal_model->getGalleryImage($username);

        var_dump($galleryImage);




        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
        $this->load->view('shared/nav');
        $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $viewData);
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');


    }
}

function index()
{

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


    $this->load->library('upload');

    $data['gal_model'] = $this->gal_model->getGalleryImage($username);

    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['images'] = $this->gal_model->getGalleryImage($username);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galtitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('gallery/galview', $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

}

 }
```

Model:

```
class Gal_model extends CI_Model
{
var $gallery_path;


function Gal_model()
{
    parent::__construct();


}   


function exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from("gallery")->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
    }

    else

    {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
    }

}



function putGalleryImage($username, $galleryImage)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'galleryimage' => $galleryImage);
    $this->session->set_userdata($galleryImage);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('gallery', $record);


    }


}

function getGalleryImage($username)
{

    $this->db->select('*')->from('gallery')->where('user', $username);

    $imagesSet= $this->db->get();

    $images = array();

    foreach ($imagesSet->result() as $row)
    {
        $images[] = array('imageid' => $row->imageid,
                'user' => $row->user,
                'galleryimage' => $row->galleryimage);
    }
    return $images;


}

 }
```

View:

```
 <div id="gallery">
   <?php if (isset($images) && is_array($images)):
    foreach($images as $galleryImage):
    $link = $galleryImage['galleryimage'] ?>
   <div class="thumb">
        <img src="<?php  echo base_url().$link; ?>" width='150' height='100'/>
       <br>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; else:  ?>
    <div id = "blank_gallery">Please upload an Image</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
   <?=form_open_multipart('gallery/upload');?>
    <?=form_upload("userfile");?>
    <?=form_submit('upload', 'Upload')?>
    <?=form_close();?>
    <?php if (isset($error)) echo $error;?>
```

Thanks again for the help guys

Comment: For each user try from a different browser.The sessions may be getting overwritten!. Better try from different computers connected to yours\

Comment: Hi Mevin, Ive actually tried that with no luck, but what is interesting is the Please upload an image message in the view does not display, despite no images having been uploaded yet. Im thinking is this because the browser remembers me doing this before?

Comment: I guess so. Try clearing the cache.If your on chrome try using the incognito mode

Comment: Ive tried both these things - still no luck - what else could it be? surely it couldnt be a browser setting thats stopping images from even going into a database under a different users name?

Comment: try print_r($images); inside if loop and see if it is having any content in it.

Comment: Im thinking this could be due to my put GalleryImage function having a where and insert command in its sql statement. Im thinking this is because isnt allowed in sql, could I be right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an OS problem related to directory access.

Comment: Well how come I have a similar profile image item in my application and I have no problems transferring files to the database here?

Comment: By the way I created a delete image option in my gallery and deleted the images successfully for the account I had working - now I cant add any gallery images on any account at all!

Comment: enable error_reporting and see if there is any error while adding images to db.